# Optimise a double loop in R

Tags: r, loops, optimization, vectorization

I have this double loop working:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(doe)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(rsm)) {
    if (rsm[j,2] == doe[i,2] & rsm[j,3] == doe[i,3] & rsm[j,4] == doe[i,4]) {
      out <- cbind(doe[i,6], rsm[j,6])
      matching_out <- rbind(matching_out, out)
      break
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have to match three columns together in two dataset (# 2, 3, 4 in this case), and then `cbind` column 6 of the two data frame in another one.

The question is: since this is quite slow, how can I optimise it? 
I suppose I could use an `apply`-like approach, but I can't figure out.

Comment: Take a look at dplyr's [joins](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html).

Comment: Try making a reproducible and example and show your desired output.

Comment: The main bottleneck here is the line  `matching_out <- rbind(matching_out, out)`. Have a look at Section 2 of http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this operation with a base `R` one-liner:

```
merge(rsm, doe, by.x=names(rsm)[2:4],by.y=names(doe)[2:4])[-(1:3)]
```